# Pokemon Infinite fusions problem dont know what to do youtube doesnt show anything that helps

Tags: crash

When I open up Pokémon Infinite Fusions it tells me:

```
Script '<internal:marshal>' line 34: TypeError occurred.

incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)

format version 4.8 required; 0.0 given



<internal:marshal>:34:in 'load'

001_SaveData.rb:28:in 'load'

001_SaveData.rb:28:in 'block in get_data_from_file'

001_SaveData.rb:27:in 'open'

001_SaveData.rb:27:in 'get_data_from_file'

001_SaveData.rb:45:in 'read_from_file'

MultiSaves.rb:118:in 'block in get_newest_save_slot'

MultiSaves.rb:77:in 'block in each_slot'

MultiSaves.rb:77:in 'each'

MultiSaves.rb:77:in 'each_slot'

MultiSaves.rb:115:in 'get_newest_save_slot'

MultiSaves.rb:638:in 'set_up_system'

999_Main.rb:143:in 'mainFunctionDe
```

(yes I did spend forty minutes typing that since I couldn't copy and paste this)

It was working like 4 hours ago perfectly fine, downloaded the game maybe two or three days ago, YouTube doesn't have any fixes so I came to reddit also I've tried reinstalling it too that didn't work though. :(

Comment: I think I have a valid fix for this Ill have to wait and see but i deleted everything copied the save file and Im going to re download the game and replace the new save with the old one

Comment: this did not work